# Can we use OpenMP with latest version of openCV

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, parallel-processing, openmp

I want to parallelize my image processing codes using openMP. I have a doubt if OpenMP is supported by the latest versions of OpenCV like 2.4.4 or 2.4.5 versions. I know abt TBB but looks too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider looking into [`cv::parallel_for_()`](http://answers.opencv.org/question/3730/how-to-use-parallel_for/). It provides a layer of abstraction for several parallelism mechanisms. If you have compiled OpenCV with OpenMP support, `cv::parallel_for_()` will use OpenMP when it can. Many OpenCV functions use `cv::parallel_for_` intenally, but you might have to dig into the source to see whether parallel execution is actually happening.